# What's the best-practice, tree-shakeable way to include Material Icons in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-material-icons

I've been trying to include a number of the Material Icons into an Angular project but each time I do I find some peculiarities.

#### 1. Icons work if *all* icons are imported

The following method does successfully include all icons into a project:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  ...
</head
```

```
// app.module
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule
  ]
})
```

```
<!-- component.html -->
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">home</mat-icon>
```

The icon is included and shows in the page as expected. However since I've never explicitly imported the one icon I'm using I have to assume that the entire module has been imported. That's a lot of code for one icon and I would prefer to import them one-by-one.

#### 2. Using MatIconRegistry to import them one-by-one throws errors

Since including the whole module leaves me with a bloated package, I instead try using `MatIconRegistry`. My understanding is that this should allow me to [register icons one-by-one](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api).

```
// app.module
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule
  ]
})
```

```
// my.component.ts

import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon'
...
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'home',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/examples/home-icon.svg')
  )
}
```

```
<!-- my.component.html -->
<mat-icon svgIcon="home" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Home icon"></mat-icon>
```

There are two problems with this though. The first is that I've no idea where that assets file is going to come from since it doesn't currently exist in my filesystem. And the second is that the the compiler doesn't like it anyhow:

```
ERROR in src/app/modules/platform/entries/entries.component.html:8:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

So the first method works but I can't make the second method work. And I fear/assume that the first method means that the entire icon set is imported making it very inefficient.

Comment: When you load the fonts via `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in your `index.html`, treeshaking is irrelevant because the icons are not bundled into your app but retrieved from `https://fonts.googleapis.com` whenever someone loads the application.

Comment: that helps in that it tells me where the icons are coming from but it doesn't help in terms of the size. It's still 80kb for just a handful of icons. Exactly as you say you can't tree-shake it but my goal *is* to be able to tree shake it.

Comment: Tree shaking doesn't apply to code that you do not distribute. You would have to build your own customized distribution of that font. But that would make your app's performance worse, not better. That puts more load on your server, will likely increase load times for your users since most people have that font cached in their browser and you may not have your own CDN, and on and on. Just leave it as is.

Comment: Apologies if I didn't explain very well :) This is for an Angular project with Ivy enabled so tree shaking happens for production builds. With the fontawesome NPM distribution you can add icons one-at-a-time to minimise bundle size. That's the same process I'm trying to use for Material icons - more on tree shaking here: https://indepth.dev/a-gentle-introduction-into-tree-shaking-in-angular-ivy/

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sadly I did not